# can you use boost library with Tcc?

Tags: c++, boost

can i precompile boost libraries so it will work with Tcc

Comment: Does Tcc support C++?

Comment: Isn't TCC C-only? Perhaps Boost.Preprocessor could be used with it, but isn't everything else written in C++? In any case, why do you use TCC?

Comment: You can compile c++ file with tcc.i used it because the fast compiling speed and portability is realy good.i finaly just compiled it for gcc and finished this problem.